# Swagger is not showing the API list while implementing with Node.js

Tags: node.js, swagger

I am trying to create API document file using swagger in Node.js but as per my code the swagger-UI is not showing anything. Its displaying the blank page. I am explaining my code below.

**app.js::**

```
const express = require('express'),
      http    = require('http'),
      cors    = require('cors'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      xss    = require('xss-clean'),
      helmet = require('helmet'),
      cluster = require('cluster'),
      os     = require('os'),
      swaggerUtill = require('./utill/swagger.utill'),
      mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');



const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'25mb'}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '25mb', extended: true}));
app.use(xss());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));


if(cluster.isMaster) {
    let length = os.cpus().length;

    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('online', (worker) => {
        //console.log(`workers are online at ${worker.process.pid}`);
    })

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        //console.log(`workers are died at ${worker.process.pid} with code ${code} and signal is ${signal}`);

        //console.log('New workers started');
        cluster.fork();
    })
} else {

    const fs = require('fs');
    const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
    const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
    const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerUtill);
    app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));
    const root_path = '/home/anil/Desktop/subhrajyoti/project/demo1/router';

    fs.readdirSync(root_path).forEach(file => {
        const split = file.split('.');
        split.pop();
        const router = require(`${root_path}/${file}`);
        app.use(`/${split[0]}`, router.getRouter());
    })


    const server = http.createServer(app);

    app.get('/', (req,res) => {
        res.status(200).render('index.html');
    })

    server.listen('3000',() => {
        console.log('server is running ar port 3000: '+process.pid);
    });
}

/*app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.status(200).render('index.html');
})*/
```

The above is my server file. I have many route files which are present inside route folder. my folder structure is like below.

```
router:
   customer.router.js
   user.router.js
   account.router.js
```

**router/customer.router.js:**

```
const express = require('express'),
      controller = require('../controller/customer.controller'),
      verify = require('../utill/verify.util.js'),
      Router = express.Router();




class DemoProjectRouter {

    getRouter() {

        try{

            Router.get('/', verify.verifyToken, controller.getCustomer.bind(controller));
            Router.post('/add',verify.verifyToken, controller.addCustomer.bind(controller));
            return Router;

        }catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new DemoProjectRouter();
```

**Updated code:**

Here I am adding my common file below.

**./utill/swagger.utill**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Yet Another Node.js demo Application API",
    "description": "Yet Another Node.js Blogg Application API",
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "host": "localhost:3000",
  "basePath": "/",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Demo",
      "description": "API for my demo applications"
    }
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "customer": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Allcustomers"
        ],
        "description": "Get All customers for our system",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "description": "Fetch all customers to our system",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "/model/customer.model"
            }
          }
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "All user fetched",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "/model/customer.model"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/customer/add": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "Name",
          "in": "body",
          "description": "Name of the customer",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "Age",
          "in": "body",
          "description": "Age of the customer",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "city",
          "in": "body",
          "description": "city of the customer",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "produces": [
          "application/json"
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "All user fetched",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "/model/customer.model"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I have so many routing files inside `router` folder, I added the swagger config file instead but after adding its giving me the following error.

**Error:**

```
Error: Provided options are incorrect.
```

Here also I have `JWT` token implementation. So I need to display all the APIs into swagger ui page and run it.

Comment: Where you have added your annotation? just put that file name located to path, here you have added `apis: ["app.js"]` but i can see here your api annotation is inside `customer.router.js` file, then put this file name like `apis: ["path to file /customer.router.js"]`, make sure that path to file need to be correct path.

Comment: I put like `apis: ["/home/anil/Desktop/subhrajyoti/project/demo1/router/customer.router.js"]` but still its not working. same issue.

Comment: No this is not correct, you have to use a relative path, Can you add your folder and file structure as hierarchy in question?

Comment: Ok, I will add. now this time I have created one `swagger.json` file to keep the configuration and importing it.

Comment: @turivishal: I updated my code also.

Comment: You have added only routes folder, where is app.js? its around route folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217351/discussion-between-subhra-edqart-and-turivishal).